# use php to increment a date one week at a time with 10 iterations

Tags: php

I want to increment a start date by 1 week 10 times. This code doesn't work:

```
<?php 

$start_date = "06/25/2012";  
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$X=1;

while ($X <= 10) {$X++; $Y=7*$X;

$date = strtotime("+ $Y days", $date);
echo date('m/d/Y', $date)."<br>";

}
```

gives:

```
07/09/2012
07/30/2012
08/27/2012
10/01/2012
11/12/2012
12/31/2012
02/25/2013
04/29/2013
07/08/2013
09/23/2013
```

This is wrong!

Comment: Try this `echo date("m.d.Y", strtotime("+1 weeks", strtotime($start_date)))`

Comment: change `$Y` to `7` $date = strtotime("+ 7 days", $date);

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are looking for this: [Online Example](https://3v4l.org/Lgrnr)

```
$start_date = "06/25/2012";  
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$X=1;

while ($X <= 10) {
    $X++; 
    $date = strtotime("+1 weeks", $date);
    echo date('m/d/Y', $date)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: The other answers were all correct, too. But this one followed the code I supplied.

Answer (score 3):

Using `DateTime` objects:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-06-25');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $date->modify('+1 week');
    echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
}
```

Ideone: https://ideone.com/7mVkmW

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will give you list of 1 week period dates 50 times.

```
<?php
$date = "05/01/2016";
$weekDates = '';

for ( $i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++ ) {
   $date = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+1 weeks", strtotime($date)));
   $weekDates .= $date . '<br>';
}

echo $weekDates;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

```
<?php 

$start_date = "06/25/2012";  
$date = strtotime($start_date);
$newDate = $date;

for ($x = 1; $x<=10; $x++)
{
    $newDate = $newDate + (86400*7);//adding the amount of seconds in a week
    $buffer = date("n/j/Y", $newDate);
    echo "{$buffer}<br>";
}
```

**Explanation of the code:**

What the previous code does is it first converts the date `"06/25/2012"` into a unix timestamp. A unix timestamp is an integer value that represents how much time (in seconds) has passed since January 1st of 1970. In the previous code, both `$date` and `$newDate` are unix timestamp values that look like the following big number: `1464330512`

From there, you want to create a loop. I preferred to use a `for` loop because it is very easy to read and suits your purpose. A `while` loop can also be done, though you would have to create a `count` of sorts if you choose that loop instead.

From there, what the code above does is that it modifies `$newDate` on every loop by adding the amount of seconds in a week to it (`86400*7`). After altering `$newDate`, the `$buffer` value then converts the `$newDate` to the same format as your original date, and echoes it.